# Is it possible to set only one branch at Databricks shared git folder(highlighted in screenshot)?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I would like to set only one branch at shared folder in databricks workspace. Attaching screenshot to give more clarity on the same.

[image]

All of data factory pipelines are using shared folder location for running notebooks and if some one changes it to other branch than production, everything starts messing up. So I would like to understand if this branch can be locked and if yes, how?
Please help..!!

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can do that by settung correct permissions on that checkout, and allow only specific users or system account (service principal on Azure) (recommended) to perform Pull operation - all other people should have just read-only permissions. (doc on [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/workspace-acl#repos-permissions))

There is also a [new functionality to set Git reference](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/jobs-remote-notebook.html) (Git URL and branch/tag/commit) directly in the job configuration so you won't even need to have a repository checked out.  This functionality was just released (as of 6th May 2022).